# How possible to emit by socket io from a different nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket IO. I have a socket managing module like bellow in my project.

manage_socket.js:

```
class mySocket{

    static manageSocket (server) {
        const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
            maxHttpBufferSize: 1e9,
              //pingInterval:25000 , pingTimeout:20000,
              //pingInterval:60000 , pingTimeout:25000, 
        });
    
        io.on("connection", (socket) => {
            console.log(`${socket.id} connected`);
            socket.on("new message", async msg => {
                
                io.emit(`incoming`, `......`);
                
            });
            
            socket.on("disconnect",  async (e) => {

                socket.disconnect();
                    
                console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
        
                io.emit(`dc`, `${socket.id} disconnected.`);
                 console.log(e);
               
            });
    
        });    
    };


}

module.exports = mySocket;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotEnv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const mySocket = require("./utils/manage_socket");
...
...
...

mySocket.manageSocket(server);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server started at port " + PORT));
```

this work fine when I use front javascript emit; But know I want to emit something from another nodejs module like myTest.js;  But I don't know is it possible and how to make that?
For example I want to do something like `io.emit("greert", "Hello. How are you?");` in myTest.js module.